# Merging two versions of a dataset in SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I have data like this:

```
email | ticket | date
a     |    1   | 1/1/2015
a     |    1   | 2/1/2015
a     |    3   | 5/6/2016
b     |    1   | 3/4/2016
b     |    2   | 7/9/2016
b     |    2   | 3/2/2016
```

I want to sum the tickets by different cuts of date, with two different potential layouts:

```
email | ticket | date
a     |    2   | 2015
a     |    3   | 2016
b     |    5   | 2016

email | 2015 tickets | 2016 tickets
a     |    2         |     3
b     |    0         |     5
```

Comment: please post your attempt and tag your dbms.

Comment: The first is a simple aggregation, but the second, are you expecting a dynamic pivot?  If so, what RDMS are you on?

Comment: RDMS is Teradata. There has been no attempt from me.

Not expecting a dynamic pivot, but not really sure what you mean that.

Comment: @NBC he was asking if you'll let the script to add the future years and not manually altered. assuming we are at 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to aggregate.

```
--Query 1
select email,sum(ticket),extract(year from date) 
from tablename
group by 1,3

--Query 2
select email
,sum(case when extract(year from date) = 2015 then ticket else 0 end)
,sum(case when extract(year from date) = 2016 then ticket else 0 end)
from tablename
group by email
```

Comment: I miss grouping by ordinals  +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti .. in fact, this is the first time i've used it here.